# Why can a zero polynomial have an infinite number of terms?

Tags: polynomials

https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/zero-polynomial/ - "A zero polynomial can have an infinite number of terms along with variables of different powers where the variables have zero as their coefficient.". Why can a zero polynomial have an infinite number of terms, while other polynomials cannot ?

Comment: Uh, because all the terms are multiplied by zero.

Comment: The same applies to other polynomials. The condition **for all polynomials** is that only finitely many terms have coefficient $\neq0$. It is usually made explicit by, for example, exhibiting a lower bound and an upper bound for the (multi)degrees of the terms, but that is unnecessary.

Comment: The zero polynomial is one that has zeros in every term, more strongly, the coefficients are all zero. One can construct an infinite number of $x{i}$ that all have zero value coefficients.

Comment: More accurately:  "A zero polynomial can have an infinite number of terms *containing* variables of different powers with zero as their coefficients."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is terrible; best to ignore it. Just take the first two sentences:

> Zero polynomial is a type of polynomial where all variable's coefficients are equal to zero. In other words, it means that all the variables have a power that is equal to zero.

Apart from the broken grammar, a power being zero (whatever that means – I guess they mean the exponent) is quite different from coefficients being zero; it’s definitely not the same thing “in other words”.

To make useful statements about these things, you first have to define exactly what you mean by a polynomial and what you mean by “its terms”.

There are (at least) three different definitions of polynomials one might consider. (I’ll talk about polynomials in one variable $x$ to keep it simple; all of this could readily also be applied to polynomials in several variables.)

a) You can define a polynomial to be a function of $x$ that can be represented as a sum of products of coefficients with powers of $x$. Note that the focus here is on functions, and the formal form (a certain type of sum of certain types of products) merely serves to represent a function.

Under this definition, there’s only one zero polynomial, *the* zero polynomial, namely the function that is identically zero, so it wouldn’t make sense to talk about “a zero polynomial”. This function can be represented in various ways, e.g. as $0$ or as $0\cdot x$ or as $0+0\cdot x^2$, but those are just different representations of the same polynomial. Typically, when speaking of “the terms of” such a polynomial, one would have in mind the minimal representation of the polynomial without unnecessary zero terms. If you allow unnecessary terms and refer to anything that can appear in some representation of a polynomial as one of “its terms”, then actually all polynomials would have all terms, since e.g. you can write any polynomial $p(x)$ as $p(x)+\pi\cdot x^7+(-\pi)\cdot x^7$, so under that definition all polynomials would have a term $\pi\cdot x^7$. That would obviously not be a very useful definition.

b) In the other extreme, you could regard a polynomial as a formal sum of terms of products of coefficients with powers of $x$. Note that the word “function” doesn’t appear in that definition. Under this definition, $0$, $0\cdot x$ and $0+0\cdot x^2$ would all be different polynomials. You could say such a polynomial is “a zero polynomial” if interpreting it as a function would yield the zero function (i.e. the function that’s identically zero). With these definitions, there would be infinitely many “zero polynomials”. It’s clear what should be regarded as “the terms” of such a polynomial defined as a formal sum, namely, simply the summands in the formal sum. Under these definitions, a zero polynomial could have any number of terms. I suspect that this is what the terrible page actually means when it says it can have “an infinite number of terms”, since the example it gives to support this claim, $0x^2 + 0x + 0$, doesn’t actually have an infinite number of terms.

c) It turns out that often, especially for algebraic purposes, it’s most useful to have a definition of polynomials that’s somewhere in between a) and b). On the one hand, there are too many different formal sums, and we’d like to consider things like $0$, $0\cdot x$ and $0+0\cdot x^2$ as identical. On the other hand, referring to the function values you get when interpreting polynomials as functions also has downsides, the main one being (I glossed over this above) that you have to specify which domain you want to evaluate them over. For instance, the polynomials $1$ and $1\cdot x^2$ are identical if you interpret them as functions over $\mathbb F_2$, the finite field of two elements, both of which square to $1$, whereas they’re different if you interpret them as functions over $\mathbb R$.

So we’d like to consider $0$, $0\cdot x$ and $0+0\cdot x^2$ to all be the same polynomial, but without referring to their evaluation as functions over some domain to decide whether they are. The way to do this is to define a polynomial as a sequence of coefficients (i.e. a function from $\mathbb N$ to the set of coefficients) with the restriction that the sequence has a finite number of non-zero terms. (If you drop that restriction, you get formal power series instead.) Under this definition, $0$, $0\cdot x$ and $0+0\cdot x^2$ are all the same polynomial, namely the one whose coefficient sequence is identically $0$, and this can be decided without reference to evaluation over some domain. Under this definition, there is again only one zero polynomial, *the* zero polynomial. One would usually regard as “its terms” the (finitely many) non-zero parts of its representation as a formal sum, but you’d certainly be free to refer to the (infinitely many) zero parts of this formal sum as “its terms”s as well. In that case, not just the zero polynomial but all polynomials would have infinitely many zero terms.